# Can't handle didSelectObject:atIndexPath: after search in TTTableViewController

Tags: iphone, search, three20

Greetings, I got some strange problem in my code...
My code is based on **Model Search** (TTCatalog) three20 example. I successfully handling *didSelectObject:atIndexPath:* when row touched before search, but this event not even firing when something is found (ex. filtered 2 results of 30).
I working with remote data, fetched once, then like in **Model Search**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code.  Your question does not have enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I've just were making huge mistake:
I've used this construction:

```
@implementation RegionSelectionViewController

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];

  TTTableViewController* searchController = [[[TTTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  searchController.dataSource = [[[RegionDataSource alloc] initWithDuration:1.5] autorelease];
  self.searchViewController = searchController;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
}
```

instead of this:

```
@implementation RegionSelectionViewController

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];

  RegionSelectionViewController* searchController =
    [[[RegionSelectionViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  searchController.delegate = _delegate;
  self.searchViewController = searchController;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Now it's working as it should!

Looks like there are no option to overload delegate of **TTTableViewController**...
One more time, thanks!

Comment: Thank you a lot. This helped me. But how do you implement it if you do not overload the delegate of TTTableViewController? Can you please give me the header file?

Comment: Sorry m8, this was long ago, and I don't work there already =) And haven't touched Three20 for about 8 months...